# In what kind of circumstances is it better to turn off the image stabilisation / vibration reduction?

Tags: image-stabilization

Just what it says in the title. I think the question is self explanatory.

Comment: That associated question is a perfect duplicate of what i want to ask. But the answers there are from 9 years ago, and there seems to be some disagreements in the answers about the state of the technology of that time, and whether newer systems are different. Are the answers on that still the same in newer systems ?

Comment: Voting to reopen to have recent answers. The user manual of my latest lens (Canon EF-S 35mm Macro) specifically says that the IS works on a tripod.

Comment: Many of Canon's Super Telephoto lenses since about 2010 or so also have IS modes for tripod use.

Comment: Not to mention that the highest voted answer to the old question was about ten years out of date when it was written. Lenses that have issues with active feedback loops when used on a tripod with IS turned on [have not been introduced since the late 1990s](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/126107/15871).

Comment: What does the owner's manual of each specific lens with IS that you use say?

Comment: Related: [Image stabilization with monopod: on or off?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72841/15871) and [Should I turn off image stabilization when I am taking a landscape shot?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/119408/15871) and [At what focal range does it make sense to have Image Stabilization turned on when using a Tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35762/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC " _What does the owner's manual of each specific lens with IS that you use say?_ " It says you may prefer to turn it off depending on shooting conditions. I was wondering, in what kind of shooting conditions, it is preferrable to turn it off.